# Topological analogue to natural transformation? (in the same way that natural isomorphisms are categorical homotopies)

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homotopy-theory, natural-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $\mathsf{C},\mathsf{D}$ categories, $I$ the interval, $\mathbb{2}$ the 2-object category with one nontrivial morphism, and $\mathsf{I}$ the 2-object category with two nontrivial inverse morphisms.

Then we say that two functors $F,G : \mathsf{C} \rightrightarrows \mathsf{D}$ are **naturally isomorphic** if there is a functor $H : \mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{I} \to \mathsf{D}$ so that, for the inclusions $i_0,i_1 : \mathsf{C} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{C} \times \mathsf{I}$, $F$ and $G$ factor through $H$ as follows: $H i_0 = F$ and $Hi_1 = G$.

The classical analogy is that natural isomorphisms are to functors are homotopies are to functions; indeed, replace $\mathsf{C}$ with $X$, $\mathsf{D}$ with $Y$, and $\mathsf{I}$ with $I$, and the above definition in $\mathsf{Top}$ is precisely the definition of a homotopy $H$ between $F$ and $G$.

This makes me wonder: *what is the topological analogue to a noninvertible natural transformation?*

A natural transformation can be defined by the above factoring, only we replace $\mathsf{I}$ with $\mathbb{2}$. This seems to suggest the idea of a "directed interval" we replace $I$ with, relaxing the requirement of a homotopy to only require one direction. But since one-directional homotopies imply bidirectional homotopies (simply "walk backwards" along the one-directional homotopy), this is not the correct notion. I have other thoughts on how to enforce extra structure, but I was wondering if more experienced category theorists or students know of a canonical notion which works-- or even better, why there isn't one!

EDIT: A **pospace** seems promising, is there a standard discussion someone can direct me to?

Comment: First of all you need an analogue for categories (as opposed to groupoids)!

Comment: Do you mean this in the sense that $\mathsf{I}$ is a groupoid? Because $\mathsf{C},\mathsf{D}$ need not be groupoids.

Comment: Directed homotopy theory is a thing

Comment: @William Topological spaces in this analogy are as to groupoids. They are fundamentally undirected. However it is not yet clear what the analogue of categories are.